# usercontrol image windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

How can I create an image icon used once I Choose Items in Tool properties to add my defined control dll into my application ? I need some code or hint to look into. Aany help ? 
[I also have a thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074943/clipmate-s-similar-function noone answers and not so many people care to view]

Comment: You want a user control??? May be you should rephrase what you want.

Comment: I want many things, not a user control, here I want an image used as default for the control I create. One that lies under the General tree view in the Tool Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Add the icon as a resource in the project. Then, use the `ToolboxBitmapAttribute` to locate it.

Try this:

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(MineGame))]
public partial class MineGame : UserControl
{
    //....
}
```

Visual Studio will try to find the icon in the assembly which contains `MineGame`.